# Adding values together javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the totals from these inputs to total up depending on what a user inputs.

This image shows what I mean:

[image]

So whatever the user types in I need each input to add up, so in the example this would be 15, but it could be anything the user types in.

Sorry I'm not up on JavaScript, so just looking for a bit of help, I have however tried the following, but it's not quite right:

```
function payableMilage(attribute)
{
    var milage = 0;
    $.each([ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday' , 'saturday', 'sunday' ], function( index, day ) {
        milage = parseInt($("input[data-attribute='payableMileage']").val());
    });
    $("#payableMileageTotal").text(milage);
}
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="control-label">Monday</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control calculate timepicker " autocomplete="off" data-day="monday" placeholder="Format: 00:00" name="monday[startTime]" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Format: 00:00" name="monday[breaks]" class="form-control calculate timepicker" autocomplete="off" data-day="monday[breaks]" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control calculate timepicker" autocomplete="off" data-day="monday" placeholder="Format: 00:00" name="monday[endTime]" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-attribute="payableMileage" min="0" name="monday[payableMileage]" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="monday[total]" type="text" class="form-control" readonly />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="monday[comments]" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you put the HTML?

Comment: "*but it's not quite right*" Can you please explain what you mean by that? Also your question should include an actual question statement and a [mcve] reproducing the problem. Without these things, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant HTML that creates those `<input>` elements as well as the attempted JavaScript. A picture can be useful, but we work with code.

Comment: Edited my post with rendered HTML

Comment: My rep isn;t high enough to post an image so posted the link to an image

Comment: Please [edit] your example to be ***Minimal*** (only the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing mor),  ***Complete*** (all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue) and ***Verifiable*** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). Please use the [the button that looks like this](http://stackoverflow.com/content/balsamiq/wmd-mockup-button.png) to put your code into a runnable snippet so that *you* can verify that that the code in your question reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will get only the **last value**, because you are assigning not adding. Change your code to:

```
milage += parseInt($("input[data-attribute='payableMileage']").val());
//-----^^
```

Comment: I added the + but it doesn't add up properly.

Comment: @theUnified Can you create a fiddle or post the full code?

Comment: Edited my original post with html

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
milage += parseInt($("input[data-attribute='payableMileage']").val());
```

to

```
milage += parseInt($("input[name='"+day+"[payableMileage]']").val());
```

Now works, my bad but people pointing different things out made me think, sorry if I wasted anyones time.